# XMonad Layout for portrait monitor

Tags: xmonad

My monitor arrangement includes two 27" monitors in profile orientation. The `Tall` layout (the default layout for XMonad) is a pretty poor choice for my monitor setup, but after looking through the layout gallery it appears that most layouts assume a landscape monitor.

Are there any good layouts for profile monitors? Maybe something like `Tall` but it splits horizontally first and then vertically between non-master windows?

My monitor setup:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4800 x 2560, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+2880+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1368x768       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   960x540        60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   864x486        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   720x405        60.0  
   640x360        60.0  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 connected primary 1440x2560+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   3440x1440_40.00   40.0 +
   2560x1440      60.0*+
   2880x1620      60.0  
   2560x1440_40.00   40.0  
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       74.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1-2 connected 1440x2560+1440+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440      60.0*+
   3440x1440      40.0  
   2880x1620      60.0  
   2560x1440_40.00   40.0  
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       74.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to [rotate the Tall layout by 90 degrees](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Layout.html#t:Mirror).

The minimal example how to use this is to place this layout into the `layoutHook` of your Xmonad configuration.

```
 main = do
     xmonad $ defaultConfig { layoutHook = Mirror $ Tall 1 (3/100) (0.5) }
```

This makes Xmonad use `Tall` layout with 1 master area, `3/100` increments and a ratio of 50 percent. `Mirror` turns this layout 90 degrees.